# How to send data from input without a ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field with a number in it. I want to make it possible to edit the field and update it. So it is like an input field with the number 5 and when i change it to 6 it has to automatically update it self. So if i refresh the page the number should have been updated to the number 6. I've tried it with ng-change but it didnt work.. The code that i used was:

```
<input type="text" ng-change='change(di)' value="{{di.hours}}">
```

To test the ng-change i used the following code in my Controller

---

```
$scope.change = function(data){
    alert(data);
};
```

The problem was, it didn't alert anything when i had changed my input.

Comment: you are missing `ng-model`.

Comment: oh yes.. that was kind of stupid.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using ng-model to bind input to some property of scope.
To detect changes of scope you can use $watch function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-model="{{di.hours}}"` instead to bind input, you will get value automatically.
And do not use `ng-change`
you can do `$watch` in angular controller like

```
scope.$watch('di.hours', function(newVal, oldVal) {
              alert(newVal);
        });
```